# css rule in stylesheet but not applied in browser

Tags: css

I'm making a grid in html:

```css
 *,
 *:after,
 *:before {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box sizing: border-box;
 }
 .mygrid {
   margin: 0 0 20px 0;
 }
 &:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
 }
 [class*='col-'] {
   float: left;
   padding-right: 20px;
 }
 .grid &:last-of-type {
   padding-right: 0;
 }
 .col-1-2 {
   width: 33.3%;
 }
 .col-2-3 {
   width: 66.6%;
 }
 .content {
   background-color: #8AB9FF;
   padding: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div class="col-1-2">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2-3">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All changes apply on document except last rule on `.content`. When I fire up document in browsers (chrome, mozilla, i.e.) and inspect element I can't see the color rule, but can see the other rules created.

Comment: It seems to be working (at least in the stacksnippet).

Answer (score 0):

As can i see, the boxes are blue. Maybe there are more rules, that no shown here and interfere with your intent. But if you don't see the rule on the debugger, could be a simple syntax error in the production document. Not in this example.

EDIT:

You should "inspect element" and lookup `.content` rule. If inside you see something like this <strike>background-color: #8AB9FF;</strike> then another rule is overriding. Try this.

```
background-color: #8AB9FF !important;
```

Example:

```css
*,
 *:after,
 *:before {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .mygrid {
   margin: 0 0 20px 0;
 }
 &:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
 }
 [class*='col-'] {
   float: left;
   padding-right: 20px;
 }
 .grid &:last-of-type {
   padding-right: 0;
 }
 .col-1-2 {
   width: 33.3%;
 }
 .col-2-3 {
   width: 66.6%;
 }
 .content {
   background-color: #8AB9FF !important;
   padding: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div class="col-1-2">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2-3">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it looks like there must be external rules/code/environment(?) that affects this it works fine for me as well.

Comment: same here this is working maybe you can use the chrome inspector and trace exactly what rule is overwriting the `.content` class

Comment: I agree with @ncubica use chrome inspect element to trace what is overriding your rule.